# Classic ASP site on Azure web site, remote mysql database

Tags: azure

I have copied a classic asp website to the new Azure websites, and was trying to get it to connect to a remote MySQL database (remote being not hosted on Azure).  I am getting a internal server error message, and the detailed logs seem to point to an issue with my connection string.

The current string is setup as below:

```
database_string = "Driver={mySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver}; Server=server.com; Port=3306; Option=0; Socket=; Stmt=; Database=mydb; Uid=user; Pwd=password;"

and the ADODB connection is setup like such;
Set area_rec = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
area_rec.ActiveConnection = MM_database_STRING
```

I am having a hard time seeing the specific error, but a couple questions if anyone could provide some guidance.

1. I am assuming remote databases are supportable in the first place
2. Is the connection string correct?
3. Do I need to setup a linked resource
4. If I finally get it all ported to SQL Azure, any issue with using ADODB recorsets?

Thank you much for any help, I have struggled with this for a while.

Answer (score 2):

They don't support connection to external database which is not hosted by them or ClearDB.

Setup your own MYSQL in VM or use ClearDB.

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for doing this from classic asp on an azure website - even to clear db, the MYSQL ODBC driver will not be installed. The only way on Azure is in a VM.