# Intermittent Errors connecting to MySQL server

Tags: mysql, asp.net, azure

My app seems to run fine sometimes, and other times it says it cannot connect to any of the MySQL servers.

I started out with the MySQL server being hosted in azure as well, but I moved it external due to connectivity issues.

I finally moved the ASP.Net app to a real VM instead of being hosted as a website. I tested a manual connection to the MySQL server when it became unresponsive and it failed as well. I then did a trace route to the server and it failed as well.

Is this a known issue? Is this a duplicate of: [Classic ASP site on Azure web site, remote mysql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12647089/classic-asp-site-on-azure-web-site-remote-mysql-database)

Comment: Transient failure is a fact of life for cloud-deployed solutions and your application should cope with them.The fact that you are unable to connect a VM to an externally hosted MySQL instance may be due to firewall rules at the MySQL hosting provider's end as there should be nothing blocking the outbound traffic from your Azure VM.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm sure the issue was not with the externally hosted MySQL database, because in one of the tests it was hosted on my machine and I tested from other locations as well. It seems like a failure on the provider's part if I am unable to connect to an IP on a regular basis that others have no issues with.